# Multiprocessing Pool Job output

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, jupyter-notebook

I am using an open source project for fun, but not getting past it's utilization of BH-TSNE via multiprocessing pool.

Github Source :

https://github.com/kylemcdonald/AudioNotebooks/blob/master/Fingerprints%20to%20t-SNE.ipynb

specific error :

```
data = data.astype(np.float64)
def job(params):
    start = time()
    tsne(data, data_root, mode, initial_dims=params[0], perplexity=params[1])
    print 'initial_dims={}, perplexity={}, {} seconds'.format(params[0], params[1], time() - start)
params = list(itertools.product(initial_dims, perplexities))
pool = Pool()
pool.map(job, params)

utils/bhtsne.py:129: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  for sample in samples:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-0350579d447b> in <module>()
      7 params = list(itertools.product(initial_dims, perplexities))
      8 pool = Pool()
----> 9 pool.map(job, params)

/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.pyc in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    249         '''
    250         assert self._state == RUN
--> 251         return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
    252 
    253     def imap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=1):

/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.pyc in get(self, timeout)
    565             return self._value
    566         else:
--> 567             raise self._value
    568 
    569     def _set(self, i, obj):

AssertionError: ERROR: Call to bh_tsne exited with a non-zero return code exit status, please refer to the bh_tsne output for further details
```

I have the `bh_tsne` wrapper, the binary too..

Wrapper Source : https://github.com/lvdmaaten/bhtsne

but unclear how I watch that subprocesses output.

Looked at a few google searches, turned on Verbose mode in the wrapper to default.. but no output seems to appear either in the DIR or Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that Jupyter Notebook doesn't play well with this type of code.. but it turned out to be an issue with my computer environment underneath.. had to build `numpy` from source with stuff enabled

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9254

What's important is.. if you crash in jupyter notebook, and the crass occurred in a thread inside a pool.. there's no way to see the trace AFAIK.. and the work around is to just run the code straight in the notebook or switch to non-iPython